# Getting empty data in AJAX after POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a Trading system and I'm using php to get some data, but when it arrives it is empty. It's the first time I use AJAX and I don't know what am I doing wrong. Here is my code:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').click(function(){

        //Get the values
        var amount     = $('#amount').val();
        var from       = $('#from').val();
        var to         = $('#to').val();

        var params = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("' + from + to +'")';
        console.log( params );
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "currencies.php",
            data: params,
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
                alert(data); //I'm alerting because I was not receiving nothing at #result

            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

$yql_query = $_REQUEST['params'];
$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json" . "&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env";

$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json = curl_exec($session);

$phpObj =  json_decode($json);
$conversiones = $phpObj->query->results->rate;
$title = new ArrayObject();


$title = "$conversiones->Name";

echo $title;
```

I typed:

```
params=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20("MXNUSD")
```

in the URL, to see if the PHP file is working and it is. It echoes the Name of the currencies, but is not received in the script.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Fixed typos.

Comment: Add an `error` handler to the ajax function so see what goes wrong

Comment: Oh, and `$phpObj` is not the same as `$phpObj2`, you have a typo there

Comment: First of all I think you need to pass from and to to php file and then process SQL statement there. It doesn't solve your problem, but still))

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I have other names for the variables but changed them in here and didn't see that number. I was ok ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send a key/value pair. All you are sending is a value without the `params` key.

The `key` is what you are using in your php `$_REQUEST['params']`

Look in your browser console network tab and you won't see the same url as what you manually put in address bar

Try

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "currencies.php",
        data: {params: params}, // object for key/value
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
            alert(data); 

        }
    });
```

Also note that you can only print the json without any extra `echo` in php. Otherwise will get json parse error in ajax

Just as an FYI - you can make this same request directly to Yahoo right from browser without a proxy in php on your server. See [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it solved my problem and you gave me a second alternative. I made it with a php on my server because I am trying to learn more about it since I'm new to php. Thank you very much!